# In Clan Wars, what factors are used to determine the opponent clan?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In the clan wars matchmaking, what criteria is used to determine the clan that you are fighting against? Is it based on Clan Total Points (i.e. trophies), or something else?

If you win many wars in a row, does this mean you will get harder opponents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How are clans matched for a clan war?**

> Clan wars matchmaking matches clans based on the **strength** of their members. Unlike multiplayer battles, **trophies have no influence in determining your clan wars opponent**. After an opposing clan is found, the war immediately starts. There’s no “nexting” in clan wars matchmaking. In addition to that, any inactive members in a clan will be treated as an active member.

**How is strength calculated in clan wars?**

> Strength is based on each member’s attacking power (troops, army camp capacity, spells and heroes) and defensive strength (defense buildings, walls, traps and heroes). Different layouts and base designs do not affect strength. The only way a member’s strength can be changed is if they upgrade their troops, defenses, spells, etc.

So if you win a lot of matches, you will not be facing any harder clans. Only if you upgrade your base, attack or defense(the strength), will you face harder opponents.

---

[Source](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars_FAQ)