# Does your offense affect who your opponent is in Clan War?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In Clan Wars your opponent is determined by your clan's average base value, would a player's offense affect what clan you go up against?

Comment: Answered in [How is Clan War Map position determined?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168192/how-is-clan-war-map-position-determined?rq=1)

Comment: Hmm, [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/191452/58396) is actually the proper dup. I didn't see that Q before answering, oh well... The other linked question is about war position and not clan matchmaking

Comment: @angussidney I already know how the positions are determined!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [wikia](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars_FAQ#How_is_strength_calculated_in_clan_wars.3F), yes, a player's offense also affects the matchmaking algorithm:

> Strength is based on each member's attacking power (troops, army camp capacity, spells and heroes) and defensive strength (defense buildings, walls, traps and heroes). Different layouts and base designs do not affect strength. The only way a member's strength can be changed is if they upgrade their troops, defenses, spells, etc.

Otherwise, I do not recall any official statement from SuperCell for how the algorithm work.